# Is there a way to select the output device for an audio from a web page?

Tags: html, flash, web-applications, audio

The web app I'm building has audio notifications and a video conference option, so the user normally is going to have speakers and a headset connected to the PC, my client wants that the audio notifications will be played in the main speakers, and the video conference can be done using the headset.

Right now I'm using all html5 for audio and webRTC for video conference, I couldn't find any info about how to do this. May be with flash but not can't find this either.

Comment: The browser is not aware of audio devices. They are controlled at an OS level.

Comment: It'd be nice if they let you, though. I use multiple sound outputs and would love to have some control over that without resorting to ugly plugins in the browser.

Comment: You might want to check the [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html). I don't know if you can change the audio context destination, but that could be a way out.

Comment: This is a great feature and i am looking for new chrome extensions that implements that. I have two monitors and in one i have one chrome tab that could use the headset output to navigate and in other monitor with another chrome tab i could use the speakers output for the whole family e.g ambient music.

Answer (score 11):

Solutions in this space are emerging via the use of WebRTC. You can see a sample of a working solution at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Browser support for this is limited right now though.

Comment: There is already an app to do this. See https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audiopick/gfhcppdamigjkficnjnhmnljljhagaha

Answer (score 1):

Actually sound output is only on Oslevel ... you may have to read about the chrome.audio API which still on experimental level ... 
"The chrome.audio API is provided to allow users to get information about and control the audio devices attached to the system. This API is currently only implemented for ChromeOS. "

I thnik this would help if it was availble for all OS so you could redirect sound using this API ... 
As exemple of some methods from this API i can list :

```
getInfo − chrome.audio.getInfo(function callback)
```

which return all audio  output and input devices

```
setActiveDevices − chrome.audio.setActiveDevices(array of string ids, function callback)
```

which sets the active devices to the devices specified by |ids|

The problem is Chrome.audio API is only for ChromeOS and sounds output is controlled by other OS... that's it two parallel lines..

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this in your javascript code.

```
 audioElement.setSinkId(deviceId);
```

Comment: This doesn't work!

Comment: not supported on mobile browsers

Answer (score 1):

There is now an HTML5 audio device redirector Chrome extension called **AudioPick**.  The website is here: https://rain-fighters.github.io/AudioPick/

This is OpenSource under the GNU public license, with a [Github repo](https://github.com/rain-fighters/AudioPick).

There are some limitations (no Flash sources, and some types of HTML5 sources also will not be found), as indicated on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't done that before, it looks like this is possible nowadays with the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

You can search for audio devices with [`MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then((devices) => {
        const outputDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === 'audiooutput');
        console.log('available output devices:', outputDevices);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
    });
```

Then you need an `AudioContext` where you set the desired output device via [`setSinkId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/setSinkId).

I hope this helps as a starting point.